# Faster way to join columns with a very large number of rows?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

**Table 1: table_of_articles_with_tags**

```
doc_id   tag
100      apples
100      apples
200      bananas
400      pears
```

This table has 249,934 rows.

**Table 2: table_of_tags**

```
tag_id   tag
1        apples
2        bananas
3        oranges
4        pears
```

This table has 34,886 rows.

**I want to create this third table:**

```
tag_id   doc_id
1        100
1        100
2        200
4        400
```

Essentially, I want to replace the tag names with the respective id numbers.

Currently, I've added a tag_id column to the table_of_articles_with_tags and I'm running this query:

```
UPDATE table_of_articles_with_tags t1
INNER JOIN table_of_tags t2
ON t1.tag = t2.tag
SET t1.tag_id = t2.id;
```

This query has been running for many, many hours.

Is there a faster way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add and index on table_of_tags.tag:

```
ALTER TABLE table_of_tags ADD INDEX idx_tag (tag);
```

and if not enough, you can do the same on table_of_articles_with_tags.tag.

Your query will UPDATE an existing table, if you want to create a new table instead you should use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE third_table AS
SELECT
  t2.tag_id,
  t1.doc_id
FROM
  table_of_articles_with_tags t1 INNER JOIN table_of_tags t2
  ON t1.tag = t2.tag
```

Comment: I added indices to both tables and the query executed in 3 seconds, but the query doesn't do anything.

Comment: @fireundubh please see my updated answer, if you want to create a new third table you need to use a CREATE query and not an UPDATE query